# Is there way to render chart 'CanvasJS' in 'PopUp' element in 'Leaflet' map on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, leaflet, canvasjs

I'm trying to put chart in the Pop Up on leaflet map in React.
So, I want when a user clicks on the marker to load chart.
Maybe the mistake is in my code on this line:

```
chart.render();
```

I have two componentDidMount may be this is wrong..
When I save the code in VS Code I not have erros, but when I open the page I see this error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'render' of
>   undefined
>       (anonymous function)
>       C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/leaflet-web - test/src/App.js:2024

Im really new in ReactJS and can I get example how to fix my code to work when Users click on the markers map then load chart.

The code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Map as LeafletMap, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import CanvasJSReact from './assets/canvasjs.react';
var CanvasJSChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSChart;

var dataPoints = [];

const customMarker = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/browse/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-shadow.png",
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [10, 41],
  popupAnchor: [2, -40]
});

class Map extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      coords: [
        { lat: 41.19197, lng: 25.33719 },
        { lat: 41.26352, lng: 25.1471 },
        { lat: 41.26365, lng: 25.24215 },
      ],
      zoom: 7,
      dats: null,
    };
  }
  /*
    async componentDidMount() {
      const url = "http://192.168.0.1:8000/?date=2019-10-20&id=4&daysForward=2";
      const response = await fetch(url);
      let data = await response.json();
      this.setState({ dats: data.aladinModel[0] });
      console.log(this.state.dats[0].RH);
  }*/

  componentDidMount() {
    var chart = this.chart;
    fetch('http://192.168.0.1:8000/?date=2019-10-20&id=4&daysForward=3')
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.aladinModel[0].length; i++) {
          dataPoints.push({
            x: new Date(data.aladinModel[0][i].DATS),
            y: data.aladinModel[0][i].TA
          });
        }
        chart.render();
      }
      );
  }

  render() {
    const options = {
      theme: "dark2",
      animationEnabled: true,
      zoomEnabled: true,
      title: {
        text: "Данни на 3 часа"
      },
      axisX: {
        title: "Период",
        suffix: "",
        valueFormatString: "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm",
        crosshair: {
          enabled: true,
          snapToDataPoint: true
        }
      },
      axisY: {
        title: "Температура (°C)",
        includeZero: false,
        crosshair: {
          enabled: true,
          snapToDataPoint: true
        }
      },
      data: [{
        type: "scatter",
        markerSize: 15,
        toolTipContent: "<b>Дата: </b>{x}<br/><b>Температура: </b>{y}°C",
        dataPoints: dataPoints
      }]
    }
    const { coords, zoom } = this.state;
    return (
      <LeafletMap
        center={[42.733883, 25.48583]}
        zoom={zoom}
        style={{ height: "100vh" }}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />

        {coords.map(({ lat, lng }, index) => (
          <Marker position={[lat, lng]} icon={customMarker} key={index}>
            <Popup>
              {index + 1} is for popup with lat: {lat} and lon {lng}
              <CanvasJSChart options={options}
              /* onRef={ref => this.chart = ref} */
              />
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        ))}
      </LeafletMap>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

**I want this chart** [image: scatter chart] **to be displayed in this PopUp** [image: Leaflet PopUp].
**The data is from Node Express API** [image: DATA API]

So the original code for scatter chart who I want to display on my PopUp is this one:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CanvasJSReact from '../../assets/canvasjs.react';
var CanvasJSChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSChart;

var dataPoints = [];
class ScatterChart extends Component {
    render() {
        const options = {
            theme: "dark2",
            animationEnabled: true,
            zoomEnabled: true,
            title:{
                text: "Данни на 3 часа"
            },
            axisX: {
                title:"Период",
                suffix: "",
                valueFormatString: "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm",
                crosshair: {
                    enabled: true,
                    snapToDataPoint: true
                }
            },
            axisY:{
                title: "Температура (°C)",
                includeZero: false,
                crosshair: {
                    enabled: true,
                    snapToDataPoint: true
                }
            },
            data: [{
                type: "scatter",
                markerSize: 15,
                toolTipContent: "<b>Дата: </b>{x}<br/><b>Температура: </b>{y}°C",
                dataPoints: dataPoints
            }]
        }

        return (
        <div>
            <h1>Температурна графика - трябва да се кликне два пъти ! //бъг за чистене</h1>
            <CanvasJSChart options = {options} 
                /* onRef={ref => this.chart = ref} */
            />
            {/*You can get reference to the chart instance as shown above using onRef. This allows you to access all chart properties and methods*/}
        </div>
        );
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        var chart = this.chart;
        fetch('http://192.168.0.1:8000/?date=2019-10-20&id=4&daysForward=3')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.aladinModel[0].length; i++) {
                    dataPoints.push({
                        x: new Date(data.aladinModel[0][i].DATS),
                        y: data.aladinModel[0][i].TA
                    });
                }
                chart.render();
            }
        );
    }
}

export default ScatterChart;
```

**So I copy the libraries from my assets folder and copy this code into my code.. but Without result..**

Comment: You cannot include a `componentDidMount` method inside the `render` method. This is not allowed.

Comment: can you provide where your component is instanciated ? you just gave the compoonent here

Comment: I move componentDidMount before render and the error is the same..

Comment: François Richard I cannot understand you.

Comment: Can I get example to remember that ?

Comment: chart.render() won't render the component

Comment: I see that.. really clear..

Comment: Please provide a sample of the chart data you are receiving in order to display them into the marker

Comment: I update my question.

Comment: I update for third time the question and paste the original code only for chart.. 
I try to copy this code into my code.. but I have some trouble to display this chart..